# Repeating text in the beginning of certain pages

Tags: afterpage, everypage

With the following code, the text

*This is an experiment!*

is not placed in the indicated pages: 1, 2 and 4.

Could somebody please help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage,everypage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand*{\MyList}{1,2,4}

\newcommand*{\AddMyText}{
    \foreach \x in \MyList {
        \IfEq{\arabic{page}}{\x}{
           \afterpage{\noindent \centering This is an experiment!}
           \breakforeach%
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\AddEverypageHook{\AddMyText}

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Comment: normally such text would be in the page heading, do you really need it to be in the main text block?

Comment: Just remove `\afterpage` and add `\par` after "experiment!"

Comment: @Fran Thanks! That works.